# Real-time statistics (example). NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, performance, redis, nosql

#### Task

Hi I have `2-3` thousands of users `online`. I also have groups, teams and other(2-3) entities which have users. So for about every `10 seconds` I
want to show online statistics (query various params of users and other entities). And every, I believe, `5 - 30 seconds` user can change his status. Every `1 hour` move to another group or team or whatever. What no-sql database should I use ? I dont have experience, just know no-sql is quite fast and just read a little about `Redis, MongoDB, Cassandra`.

Of course, I store this data model in RDBMS (except online status and statistics).

#### I think about next solution:

Store all data in json. use Redis. prepend id prefix (EX 'user_'+userId)

```
user_id:{"status":"123", "group":"group_id", "team":"team_id", "firstname":"firstname", "lastname":"lastname", ... other attributes]}

group_id:{users:[user_id,user_id,...], ... other group attributes}
team_id:{users:[user_id,user_id,...], ... other team attributes}
...
```

What would you recommend or propose? Will it be convenient to query such data?
Maybe I can use some popular standard algotithms to query statistics (ex monte-carlo algotithm for percentage statistics, I dunno). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Redis Hyperloglog](http://redis.io/commands#hyperloglog), a feature added in Redis 2.8.9. 
This [blog post](http://redislabs.com/blog/how-to-use-redis-at-least-x1000-more-efficiently) describes how to calculate very efficiently some statistics that look quite similar to the ones you need.